# return json data using ajax in laravel not working

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to receive an id by first sending it through ajax and then return it in json format in laravel. For some reason, it's not working, also console shows I'm getting a "Internal server error" for this url: `http://localhost/public/admin/questions/sort`

What could be wrong here?

jquery code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //alert(url);
                $('select[name=selector]').change(function() {
                    var quiz_id=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '{{ route('admin.questions.sort') }}',
                    data:{id:quiz_id}
                    }).done(function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg['id']);
                    })
                });
            });
        </script>
```

routes file

```
Route::post('questions/sort',['uses'=>'QuestionController@sort','as'=>'admin.questions.sort']);
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionController');
```

controller file

```
   public function sort(Request $request) {
        $id=$request['id'];
        return response()->json(['id'=>$id  ],200);
    }
```

Comment: You should parse JSON response in ajax success callback. Use `msg = JSON.parse(msg)` when you are getting ajax response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to GET data not POST. Try changing your ajax POST and in routes file to GET

Answer (score 0):

$request is an object so you access it as an object not array

```
public function sort(Request $request) {
    $id=$request->input('id');
    return response()->json(['id'=>$id  ],200);
}
```